RotatingFileHandler keeps log file open
I use RotatingFileHandler to rotate my log files on a Python app:
    logger.addHandler(
        RotatingFileHandler(
            filename=args.log_file, mode="w", maxBytes=1_000_000, backupCount=4
        )
    )

The app keeps running for several days, generating 4 log files, each being 1M. I discovered that the latest file seems still open by the app:
[my@myhost monitoring *PROD*]$ sudo lsof -a +L1 /app
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE   SIZE/OFF NLINK     NODE NAME
python3 44759 me    3w   REG  253,3 4346986722     0 50375001 /app/exploit/monitoring/monitoringd.log.4 (deleted)

As you can see the file size is quite big, 4.3Gb. In order to get back the disk, I have to restart the app.
Did anyone get this error? Did you find a fix for this?
I use Python 3.9.18.

I recommend updating to Python 3.13.0 or Python 3.12.7 over the weekend. There are no bugs present.
